# Is there an equivalent in Java to C#'s Lookup data structure?

Tags: java, c#, linq

.Net's LINQ has the [`Lookup<TKey, TElements>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) data structure where for a given key, multiple values can be stored.

What is an equivalent data structure in Java?

Comment: There is no specific data structure to store a single key with multiple values, but there are other options where you can store one key with multiple value.

Answer (score 0):

Guava's [`MultiMap`](https://www.google.co.il/url?q=https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwjr5tLkwtzZAhVqMZoKHdoYDpQQFggLMAA&usg=AOvVaw1Q4HFIJg8oNjmjV-jTrfKr) seems to be a good parallel to LINQ's `Lookup`.